# Struts 1.3 Passing undeclared value to mapping.findForaward

Tags: mapping, struts-1, struts-action

In Struts 1.3 Action class, we return value as

```
return mapping.findForward("success");
```

What will happen if "success" is undefined in the action tag for that action

```
   <action path="/helloWorld"
    type="com.action.HelloWorldAction"
    name="helloWorldForm">
    <forward name="good" path="/Good.jsp"/>
    <forward name="bad" path="/Bad.jsp"/>
   </action>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

findForward method looks for a named forward that you defined with the action mapping. Since you have not defined forward name for "success", it should give blank page.

Answer (score 0):

You will be forwarded to a blank page.